# Passing a java bean from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I found out plenty of solutions but none of them work for me.

This is the bean in jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="customer" class="com.objects.Customer" scope="request" />
<form action="proceed" method="post">
    <% customer.setEmail("abc");%>
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed" />
</form>
```

This is the servlet

```
Customer customer = (Customer)request.getAttribute("customer");
System.out.println(customer.getEmail());
```

Then it just boom, the customer object is null. I tried to change to session and getsession but still didn't work at all.

Could anyone point my mistake.? Thanks

Comment: in which servlet's method did you write this code?

Comment: @Miguel: In the `doPost()`. OP apparently expected that the form submit magically uses the very same HTTP request instance as it was when the form was displayed, with all attributes still present.

Answer (score 3):

Request attributes don't work this way. The customer bean is instantiated on the `request` object corresponding to the **previous** request: the one that displays the form. When you submit the form to the servlet the request where you put the `customer` object is long gone.

But it should work with `<jsp:useBean id="customer" class="com.objects.Customer" scope="session" />` and `session.getAttribute("customer")` because the `session` objects spans multiple requests assuming you have cookies enabled in the browser. If it's not working then you have another issue not visible in your provided code.

One more suggestion: use standard `<jsp:setProperty name="customer" property="email" value="abc" />` to set bean values.